# Jade not working on Angular Routing

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, pug

I am using expressjs for webserver , along with jade. i am doing client side routing using angularjs but my UI is not what I expected 
here is my code and output

```
var express = require('express');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');



app.get('/', function (req, res) {

res.render("layout.jade");

});

app.listen(3030);
```

layout.jade

```
doctype html
html(ng-app="myapporder")
head
    title my orders app
    include scripts.jade
body
    block body
        h1 orders
            div(ng-view)
```

angapp.js

```
(function(){

var app = angular.module('myapporder' , ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider){

    $routeProvider
        .when('/' , {
            controller : 'customerController' ,
            templateUrl : 'customer'

        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo :'/'});

  });



  }());
```

customer.jade

```
div.container
    p.
        Search <input type='text' ng-model='cusfil'></input> 
    table.table.table-hover.table-bordered
        tr
            th(ng-click="dosort('name')") name
            th(ng-click="dosort('city')") city
            th(ng-click="dosort('cost')") cost
            th(ng-click="dosort('date')") date
        tr(ng-repeat='cust in customers | filter:cusfil | orderBy:sortby:reverse')
            td {{ cust.name}}
            td {{ cust.city}}
            td {{ cust.cost | currency}}
            td {{ cust.date}}
    span total customers {{customers.length}}
```

customercontroller.js

```
(function(){


var CustControl = function ($scope){

    $scope.customers=[{name:'tina' , city:'yina' , cost :4.9987 , date:'200-12-11'} , 
    {name:'yina' , city:'yina' , cost :3.44 , date:'200-12-11'}];
    $scope.dosort = function(idw){
        $scope.sortby = idw;
        $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
    };

}

angular.module('myapporder').controller('customerController' , CustControl);


}());
```

instead of showing the text output also shows div , h1 etc. tags
output

orders
div.container p. Search  table.table.table-hover.table-bordered tr th(ng-click="dosort('name')") name th(ng-click="dosort('city')") city th(ng-click="dosort('cost')") cost th(ng-click="dosort('date')") date tr(ng-repeat='cust in customers | filter:cusfil | orderBy:sortby:reverse') td td td td span total customers 2

Comment: Do you mean that your customer.jade isn't rendered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't render Jade templates on the client side. The server needs to render them.

So youc could add a route to your express server, which renders the template.

```
app.get('/template/:name', function(req, server) {
  var name = req.params.name;
    server.render('templates/' + name);
});
```

The above code part renders the code and then edit your AngularJS route to access this URL.

```
$routeProvider
        .when('/' , {
            controller : 'customerController' ,
            templateUrl : 'template/customer.jade'

        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo :'/'});

  });
```

Comment: if i have any other angular routes , then is it must to define then in express too ?

Comment: No. If you call http://localhost:3030/template/anotherTemplate.jade 'anotherTemplate.jade' is stored in `req.params.name` So the last URL parameter is basically a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Jade templates have to be rendered by the server then sent to the client. I believe that angular routing will only take static html files unless you make a request to the server.